# How can I keep this "onclick" from happening more than once?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I am trying to have a button, that when clicked, opens up an area to type a message. I am using "onclick" in the HTML and I want it to be only clickable once. I don't want it to keep making more textarea's the more you click it.

I have a *this.onclick="null"* after the *onclick* that calls the function. This was working up until I added the submit button.

So this code works:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/question.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container {
            position: absolute;
            height: 443px;
            width: 743px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 0 0 20px 0;
            margin-top: 75px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <button id="new_message" onclick="createMessage(), this.onclick=null;">New Message</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function createMessage() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.name = "form_input";
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "messages.php";
    container.appendChild(form);

    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.name = "message_input";
    textarea.cols = 84; 
    textarea.rows = 16; 
    textarea.id = "message_input"; 
    container.appendChild(textarea);
};
```

But when I leave the HTML the same and add the submit button to the javascript like this:

```
function createMessage() {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.name = "form_input";
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "messages.php";
    container.appendChild(form);

    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.name = "message_input";
    textarea.cols = 84; 
    textarea.rows = 16; 
    textarea.id = "message_input"; 
    container.appendChild(textarea);

    var submit = document.createElement("button");
    submit.innerHTML = 'Send';
    submit.id = 'send_message';
    container.appendChild(submit); 
    submit.onClick(messageAjax());
};
```

It starts to duplicate again. Is there any way to keep this from happining?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you verify that the onclick() event has not already been set once before you add it again?

Comment: Why not just check to see if the textarea already exists before adding it?  They you would never get multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your code contains an error:

```
submit.onClick(messageAjax());
```

The property is `onclick`, in lowercase. `onClick` does not exist and throws an error. This prevents the button from having its own `onclick` cleared, since the error causes the script to stop.

I'm not entirely sure what the line above is supposed to be. It appears to be *calling* `messageAjax`, and then immediately passing that function's argument to `submit.onClick`... Did you maybe mean this?

```
submit.onclick = messageAjax;
```

Comment: Ya that worked when I just completly got rid of the onclick, but what should I do to get messageAjax to run when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: Exactly what I suggested you should replace that line with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe :

```
(function() {

    var open = false;

    function createMessage() {

        if( open ) return;

        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.name = "form_input";
        form.method = "POST";
        form.action = "messages.php";
        container.appendChild(form);

        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.name = "message_input";
        textarea.cols = 84; 
        textarea.rows = 16; 
        textarea.id = "message_input"; 
        container.appendChild(textarea);

        var submit = document.createElement("button");
        submit.innerHTML = 'Send';
        submit.id = 'send_message';
        container.appendChild(submit); 
        submit.onClick(messageAjax());

        open = true;
    };

})();
```

The closure avoids name conflict with window.open(). You could name it differently, but it's just so you know it.